# Accessing a file scope variable with internal linkage, in another scope within the same translation unit using extern

Tags: c, linkage

I am trying to access the file-scoped variable, defined with internal linkage, inside an inner block in main but the compiler is throwing an error.

> error: variable previously declared ‘static’ redeclared ‘extern’

```
//<scope1>

static int foo = 1; // Internal linkage

int main()
{ //<scope2>

    int foo = 3;

    { // <scope3>

        extern int foo;  // error
        printf("Inner main block %d\n", foo); // I want this to be 1

    } //</scope3>

    printf("main  %d\n", foo); // OK, 3 as inner scope hides outer scope

} // </scope2> 

//</scope1>
```

### C17 (6.7.9)

> If the declaration of an identifier has block scope, and the identifier has external or internal linkage,
> the declaration shall have no initializer for the identifier.

### C17 (6.9)

> There shall be no more than one external definition for each identifier declared with internal linkage
> in a translation unit. Moreover, if an identifier declared with internal linkage is used in an expression
> (other than as a part of the operand of a sizeof or _Alignof operator whose result is an integer
> constant), there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier in the translation unit.

Based on the above two statements, I interpreted that I should be able to declare foo with extern inside the inner main block and get the value of foo from the file scope as it is still within the translation unit.

Is it possible to access the foo from file scope ?

Comment: Have you studied [§6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2) and maybe [§6.2.4 Storage duration of objects](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4)?

Comment: Yes, just do `// extern int foo;` (remove) and move `int foo = 3;` below `<scope 3>` Make sure you understand what variable shadowing is. (e.g. for gcc add `-Wshadow` to be warned about the issue)

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler. I realized that based on 6.2.2, 4 and 6.2.2, 7, my program actually has undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Got it. It works now and I am able to see the warning. I'll need to research on variable shadowing.